# Javascript - How to disable color change of these stars on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am displaying the star rating of items using star rating ( value 1 to 5) as per value fetched from DB

HTML Code

```
<div class="padding-10-history">
            <div class="rate animated rubberBand" >
            <input type="radio" id="starRating5" name="rate" value="5">
            <label for="star5" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating4" name="rate" value="4">
            <label for="star4" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating3" name="rate" value="3">
            <label for="star3" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating2" name="rate" value="2">
            <label for="star2" title="text"></label>
            <input type="radio" id="starRating1" name="rate" value="1">
            <label for="star1" title="text"></label>
            </div>
```

CSS Code

```
.rate {
 height: 57px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 32px;
 width: 170px;
 margin: 0px auto;

 }
.rate label{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
margin: 0px 2px;
}
.rate label:before{
position: absolute;
left: -1px;
top: -4px;
content: "\2605";
color: #e6b507;
font-size: 36px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > input {
position:absolute;
top:-9999px;
}
.rate:not(:checked) > label {
float:right;
width:1em;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
cursor:pointer;
font-size:30px;
color:#fff;
}

.rate:not(:checked) > label:after {
 content: "\2605";
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 }

 .rate > input:checked ~ label {
 color: #ffc700;    
 }



.rate > input:checked + label:hover,
.rate > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rate > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
.rate > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
color: #c59b08;
}
```

JS Code ( to display number of stars as fetched from DB)

```
if($scope.Item.starRating === 'NULL'){
            $scope.Item.starRating = 0;
        }

        else if($scope.Item.starRating === '1'){
            document.getElementById("starRating1").checked = true;
        }

        else if($scope.Item.starRating === '2'){
            document.getElementById("starRating2").checked = true;
        }

        else if($scope.Item.starRating === '3'){
            document.getElementById("starRating3").checked = true;
        }

        else if($scope.Item.starRating === '4'){            
            document.getElementById("starRating4").checked = true;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("starRating5").checked = true;
        }
```

By checked attribute I am showing the number of stars as per rating fetched from DB. But still the colors of stars are changing when clicked. I want to stop the change of color.

I am using plain JS, not using JQuery

Comment: Your selector for the checked state is [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the one for the unchecked state. Make the unchecked state more specific.

Comment: If you don't want those inputs to be clickable use the attr `disabled` ...

Comment: @DaniP disabled is not working , I think the problem is happening due to the CSS

Answer (score 0):

Please use disabled as given below in all input:

```
<input type="radio" id="starRating1" name="rate" value="1" disabled>
```

Comment: Your solution is not working - disabled is not working , I think the problem is happening due to the CSS

Answer (score 0):

First thing First , You should not access DOM elements inside your controller, Please write a directive to do so.

using disabled seems to work. Please check the plunker solution here - https://plnkr.co/edit/QmGn4U5n4oLAG6f5EaNh

```
<div class="rate animated rubberBand" >
    <input type="radio" id="starRating5" name="rate" value="5" disabled>
    <label for="star5" title="text"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starRating4" name="rate" value="4" disabled>
    <label for="star4" title="text"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starRating3" name="rate" value="3" disabled>
    <label for="star3" title="text"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starRating2" name="rate" value="2" disabled>
    <label for="star2" title="text"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starRating1" name="rate" value="1" disabled>
    <label for="star1" title="text"></label>
```